# label value assignment is nil even after assignment

Tags: swift

```
 import UIKit
 import Foundation

class First: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var firstTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var firstTxtField: UITextField!

@IBAction func goTo2nd(sender: AnyObject) {
    var second: Second?
         second?.secondTitle.text = firstTxtField.text
}

}

import Foundation
import UIKit

class Second: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var secondTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var secondTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func goToFirstVC(sender: AnyObject) {

    var first: First?
    first?.firstTitle.text  = secondTextField.text
}



}
```

Why i'm not being able to assign textfield value to a label that is outlet, i have created 2 viewControllers in story board and have assigned each of them this (First.swift,Second.swift) classes

Comment: You need 3 different ViewController.swift files - ViewController1.swift, ViewController2.swift, ViewController3.swift

Comment: The error message explains everything, just read it carefully.

Comment: Go to each of your 3 ViewControllers in your Storyboard, control-click on the `secondTitle` and `firstTextField` and make sure their Referencing Outlet is set.  You have to connect both in all 3 ViewControllers (6 connections total).

Comment: @vacawama cannot create their outlets in other .swift files

Comment: You changed your question since my comment. Your current code is allocating a new optional variable and not setting it to anything, so of course it is `nil`.  You should search for how to pass data between view controllers.

Comment: @vacawama and everyone else thanks, i found out answer to my updated question, it can be done through properties :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class First: UIViewController {
```

//this var below is used as a property that we will be accessing by creating the object of this class in other swift classes

```
var firstTit:String?

@IBOutlet var firstTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var firstTxtField: UITextField!

@IBAction func goTo2nd(sender: AnyObject) {

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstTitle.text = firstTit
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goto2from1")
    {
        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as Second;
        svc.secondTit = firstTxtField.text
    }
}
}

import Foundation
import UIKit

class Second: UIViewController {
var secondTit: String?

@IBOutlet var secondTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secondTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func goToFirstVC(sender: AnyObject) {
}
@IBAction func goToThirdVC(sender: AnyObject) {
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   secondTitle.text = secondTit

}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goto1from2")
    {
        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as First;
        svc.firstTit = secondTextField.text
    }
    else if(segue.identifier == "goto3from2")
    {
        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as Third;
        svc.thirdTit = secondTextField.text
    }
}   
}


import Foundation
import UIKit

class Third: UIViewController {

var thirdTit:String?

@IBOutlet var thirdTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var thirdTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    thirdTitle.text = thirdTit
}
@IBAction func goTofirstFromThird(sender: AnyObject) {
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goto1from3")
    {
        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as First;
        svc.firstTit = thirdTextField.text
    }
}
}
```

another way if u don't want to pass data through 2nd ViewController, but want to send it directly to third one, use structs

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class First: UIViewController {

var firstTit:String?
@IBOutlet var firstTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var firstTxtField: UITextField!
@IBAction func goTo2nd(sender: AnyObject)
{
    Third.thirdGlobalVars.thirdTit = firstTxtField.text  //this line sends field data to third class' preperty (in fact a struct)
    //if u r going through 2nd vc to 3rd, to move from 1st vc to 2nd + if u want to do progammatic initialization use the following line as well
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondVC") as Second
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstTitle.text = firstTit
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}

class Third: UIViewController {

struct thirdGlobalVars {
static var thirdTit: String?
}
@IBOutlet var thirdTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var thirdTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    thirdTitle.text = thirdGlobalVars.thirdTit
}
```